# Schema for writing and querying Monthly Active Users (MAU) and Daily Active Users (DAU)?

Tags: cassandra

I'm using two separate tables in Cassandra to track MAU's and DAU's. The design of each table is the same:

```sql
create table log.MAU(d timestamp, userId varchar, primary key (d, userId));
```

I insert into the table every time a user logs-in or resumes their session. For the timestamp, I use the respective UTC "zero hour" (e.g. UTC midnight of the current day for DAU, and UTC midnight for the first day of the current month for MAU).

The benefits of my current design are simplicity (e.g. `select count(*) from DAU where d = ?`) and size (if a user is active, only one record for each day / month is kept).

However, the downsides are that I can't do rolling periods (e.g. active users in the past 24 hours), and I also can't track activity by each hour of each day or day of month (although I have other cassandra logs that I could possibly wrangle if I added the necessary secondary indexes).

Any thoughts on if I could track DAU's and MAU's better, given the specific downsides I mentioned or ones I haven't considered? Maybe another DB like postgres would be more appropriate? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can solve this by keying on another less-precise date column.

For monthly users, something like this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE mau(
  month bigint,
  d timestamp,
  userid text,
  PRIMARY KEY (month,d,userId));
```

Then you could query for a specific month:

```
SELECT d, userid FROM may WHERE month=201603;
```

And you could also query a range within:

```
SELECT d, userid FROM mau WHERE month=201603
  AND d>'2016-03-21 19:40:00+0000' AND d<'2016-03-21 19:50:00+0000';

 d                        | userid
--------------------------+--------
 2016-03-21 19:40:13+0000 |   tron
 2016-03-21 19:40:20+0000 |   yori
 2016-03-21 19:40:28+0000 | quorra
 2016-03-21 19:40:36+0000 |  paige

(4 rows)
```

Whether or not `month` will work for you, depends on how many rows you expect to hit per month, and how close that will put you to Cassandra's limit on 2 billion cells per partition.  Bearing that in mind it's probably a good idea to also partition by `day`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mau(
  month bigint,
  day bigint,
  d timestamp,
  userid text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((month,day),d,userId));
```

Of course, then you wouldn't be able to query an entire month at once.  But mess around with that approach, and see if you can find a PRIMARY KEY strategy that works for your application.

**EDIT 20160323**

> So in order to count the "unique" logins, I would need to do a "select count(*) distinct userId" or somesuch. I'm not terribly familiar with distinct in Cassandra but I know it works on the partition key. Given that the partition key in this schema is a combination of three columns (month,d,userId), will count distinct be allowed on the userId, alone?

No, `count` will not work on userid by iteslf.  First of all, you cannot skip PRIMARY KEY components.  Secondly, with Cassandra you need to take a query based modeling approach.  If you needed to query distinct userids that had logged-in, then you would need to new build a table to support that.

```
CREATE TABLE logins_by_user (
  userid text,
  d timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(userid,d))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (d DESC);
```

Let's say that I have the same data as above, except that user "tron" logs in for a second time:

```
SELECT * FROM logins_by_user ;

 userid | d
--------+--------------------------
 quorra | 2016-03-21 19:40:28+0000
  paige | 2016-03-21 19:40:36+0000
   tron | 2016-03-22 19:37:53+0000
   tron | 2016-03-21 19:40:13+0000
   yori | 2016-03-21 19:40:20+0000

(5 rows)
```

Querying for unique userids would yield:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM logins_by_user ;

 userid
--------
 quorra
  paige
   tron
   yori

(4 rows)
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I hope the idea leads you in the right direction.

Comment: So in order to count the "unique" logins, I would need to do a "select count(*) distinct userId" or somesuch. I'm not terribly familiar with distinct in Cassandra but I know it works on the partition key. Given that the partition key in this schema is a combination of three columns (month,d,userId), will count distinct be allowed on the userId, alone? Thanks!